# How to apply versioning strategies on config files used by .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

Think you have a .Net application using a custom config section on its config file. As the application evolves, config sections also evolve too. You distribute your application to several customers. For example, one old application uses a config file with new config section by mistake. But the application works without crash because new config file does not cause braking changes. But you have to inform the user that the config file the application used  is newer than expected. How can you apply a versioning strategy to solve this problem or anything other than versioning?

Comment: Why do you want to inform a user about the new **config file** ? What you expect, after, from him to do?

Comment: @Tigran On this case you want your application not to run.

Comment: may be, but not very clear, how you get **only** config file, and not rest... bah..

Comment: @Tigran I am not speaking for a true story that I experienced, but I just wonder the solution to this kind of problem? It is a small probability but it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear, why you have an *old* applicaiton with a *new* configuration. Usually, if there is some versioning mess, happens that you have a new software, just updated on client side, with it's own (local) version of configuration, so "old" one.

By the way, if you have a condition like you described, I think you can  for example.

- in code to check if configuation file contains more/or less, fields then expected by current application. In this case, means that configuration file is from *different* version.
- or have a version information inside configuration file and just compare two versions against each other: version of the application running and version present in config file.